# "Add new ivy" is missing

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to follow a YouTube tutorial about Vine animation. But in the video he click a button called "add new ivy" to add more vines.

[image]

But in my Blender 2.79 i cant find that option.

[image]

is there any other way i can get same effect ???

Comment: In blender you have to activate plugins in order to use them. There are a few nature plugins included in blender. Are you sure you did not skip over the plugin section of that tutorial?

Comment: @GeraldDegeneve - The add-on is definitely installed and activated, otherwise none of the other control elements would show up.